# Checking each row and adding or updating it accordingly in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from Raw Data to Consolidated Data.

If a row in the Raw Data already exists **(by checking both the Full Name and the Identity Number together with the AND Condition as the composite key of using both values is unique)** in the Consolidated Data it will check through the columns and update it if there are any changes.
For example Ben with the Identity Number of 3333 changed his Contact and Email. So after updating it will have the updated Contact and Email.

Secondly, if the row in the Raw Data doesn't exist it will add to the bottom of the Consolidated Data.
I tried a nested loop for this. I am facing the problem of duplicate entries as my code is checking the row in the Raw Data with every row in the Consolidated Data.
For example in the Raw Data I have Alan (1111), Ben (2222), Ben (3333), Calvin (4444). In the New Consolidated Data I will turn out to have more than four rows after updating.

**This is the raw data**
[image: Raw Data]

**This is the old consolidated data**
[image: Old Consolidated Data]

**This is the final consolidated data**
[image: Final Consolidated Data]

```
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    
    Set rawData = sheet1
    Set finalData = sheet2
    
    lastRow = sheet1.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    finalLastRow = sheet2.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    MsgBox lastRow
    MsgBox finalLastRow
    
    ' If the sheet is empty
    If (finalLastRow = 2) Then
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            ' Test if cell if empty
            If (rawData.range("A" & i).Value <> "") Then
                finalData.range("A" & i).Value = rawData.range("A" & i).Value
                finalData.rNeange("B" & i).Value = rawData.range("B" & i).Value
                finalData.range("C" & i).Value = rawData.range("C" & i).Value
                finalData.range("D" & i).Value = rawData.range("D" & i).Value
                finalData.range("E" & i).Value = rawData.range("E" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
        
    ' If the sheet is not empty
    ElseIf (finalLastRow <> 2) Then
    
        Dim newLastRow As Long
        newLastRow = 4
            
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            For j = 3 To finalLastRow
                ' Test if cell is the same
                'Dim matchScore As Long
                
                ' Full Name and Identity Number remain same
                If (rawData.range("A" & i).Value) = (finalData.range("A" & j).Value) And (rawData.range("B" & i).Value) = (finalData.range("B" & j).Value) Then
                    finalData.range("C" & j).Value = rawData.range("C" & i).Value
                    finalData.range("D" & j).Value = rawData.range("D" & i).Value
                    finalData.range("E" & j).Value = rawData.range("E" & i).Value
                    MsgBox "SAME"
                
                ' New Record
                Else
                   ' Check through the sheet2 to see if the row have been added to it
                    newLastRow = newLastRow + 1
                    finalData.range("B" & newLastRow).Value = rawData.range("B" & i).Value

                End If
                
                finalLastRow = sheet2.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Next j
        Next i

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added another For loop in the Else statement to check through the columns to see if it exists.

```
                ' New Record
                Else
                
                    Dim isDataInCurrentRows As Boolean
                    isDataInCurrentRows = False
                                      
                    For checkRow = 3 To finalLastRow
                    
                        If (rawData.range("B" & i).Value) = (finalData.range("B" & checkRow).Value) And (rawData.range("D" & i).Value) = (finalData.range("D" & checkRow).Value) Then
                            isDataInCurrentRows = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
            
                    Next checkRow
                    
                    If isDataInCurrentRows = False Then
                        finalData.range("A" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("A" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("B" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("B" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("C" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("C" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("D" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("D" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("E" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("E" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("F" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("F" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("G" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("G" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("H" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = rawData.range("H" & i).Value
                        finalData.range("I" & finalLastRow + 1).Value = Date
                        
                    End If
                                      
                End If
```